# What's the difference between printing the list after list.insert and printing list.insert directly?

Tags: python, list

Here, I have two examples, but I don't know why the two outcomes are different.

First example:

```
list_own=["subway", "plane", "ship","vehicle"]

list_own.insert(0,"train")

print(list_own)
```

```
['train', 'subway', 'plane', 'ship', 'vehicle']
```

Second example:

```
list_own=["subway", "plane", "ship","vehicle"]

print(list_own.insert(0,"train")
```

```
None
```

Does anyone know why the outcomes shown above are different?

Answer (score 3):

Calling the `insert` method on `list_own` inserts the element into the list the way you expected, but itself *returns* `None`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Python Documentation - Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) `insert` method of list modifies the original list but returns default value.

> You might have noticed that methods like insert, remove or sort that
> only modify the list have no return value printed – they return the
> default `None`

Which means when the modified list is printed, contents of the list gets printed but when `insert` method is called inside `print` then what `insert` returns i.e `None` that gets printed